# The KdV equation is an isospectral evolution of the Schrödinger operator?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, isospectrality

I understand that the KdV equation,

$$u_t(x,t)=-u_{xxx}(x,t)-6u(x,t)u_x(x,t)$$

is a compatibility condition of the two equations

$$\psi_{xx}(x,t)=-(u(x,t)+\lambda)\psi(x,t),$$

$$\psi_t(x,t)=u_x(x,t)\psi(x,t)+(4\lambda-2u(x,t))\psi_x(x,t).$$

In other words, if these two equations are true it implies the KdV equation. These calculations are straightforward and available [in these lecture notes.](http://www.tims.ntu.edu.tw/course/physics/handout-lecture-11.pdf)

My goal is to understand why the KdV equation is an isospectral evolution of the Schrödinger operator

$$H(\psi)=\psi_{xx}+u\psi$$

I can see why the evolution given by the KdV equation preserves the eigenvalues of $H$. But

> (1) Does it also preserve the continuous spectrum?

and

> (2) If the answer to (1) is yes, does this follow from the "compatibility condition" statement above?

Comment: Yes to (1), because the evolution of $H(u)$ is by unitary conjugation.